# Random point within oval with higher probability for a point closer to the centre?

Tags: algorithm

I feel like the question is quite descriptive but to illustrate it in words.

Picture a radial gradient (black in centre, white on edge) I want to generate a random point that is more likely to fall in the black, less likely to fall in the grey, and even less likely to fall in the white.

Could someone point me in the right direction? I'm quite stumped :/

Comment: Is the part of the main axis between the focal points to be of uniform likelyhood /"blackness"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `B` is a matrix such that `y = c + Bx` is an affine transformation which maps the unit circle to your ellipse (which is what I assume you mean by an "oval"), then a probability distribution that looks something like what you seem to want is given by `y ~ N(c, BB^T)` where `B^T` is the transpose of `B`.

You can sample from the distribution by generating a column vector `x` of two normally distributed variables and applying the transformation `y = c + Bx`. There are many libraries for generating a pair of normally distributed variables; in Java, `x0=rand.nextGaussian(); x1=rand.nextGaussian()` will work.

This will occasionally generate points outside the ellipse. You can avoid that by simply rejecting such points. Just test whether `x0*x0 + x1*x1 > 1` and reject if true.

One more thing: if you want "more white" near the edge of your ellipse, you can change the standard deviation of the gaussians you generate to a number less than 1:

```
sd = 0.5; 
do 
  x0 = sd * rand.nextGaussian(); 
  x1 = sd * rand.nextGaussian();
while (x0*x0 + x1*x1 > 1);
y0 = c0 + B[0][0] * x0 + B[0][1] * x1
y1 = c1 + B[1][0] * x0 + B[1][1] * x1
```

If you want "less white", set `sd` to some number greater than 1.

Answer (score 1):

A way to get what you want is to generate truncated normally distributed random radii r with \sigma=1 in a range +-R and uniformly distributed random values \theta in 0..pi for the polar angle.  If A and B are the major and minor axes aligned with x and y, then the points with respect to the origin are

```
x = r A/R cos \theta,   y = r B/R sin \theta
```

When you choose parameter R to be large, the values will be concentrated toward the center of the ellipse. When it's small, they'll be evenly distributed across it.

Generating pseudo random values that are truncated-normally distributed is not trivial, but not too hard either.  See e.g. [Chopin's paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1201.6140.pdf) for a good discussion. [This C++ implementation](http://miv.u-strasbg.fr/mazet/rtnorm/) looks useful.

If you don't care about all the points lying inside the ellipse, you can use the full normal distribution. The Box Muller algorithm for this is very simple to implement, and it's built into many libraries [including Java's](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextGaussian()).

Comment: To generate the random radii, fetch 4 random numbers between 0 and 50. Compute the sum of those numbers, subtract 100, and then divide by 100. The result is a number between -1 and 1, with a decent-looking bell-shaped distribution.